# ¿Cómo cambiar el DocumentRoot en LAMP (Apache, MySQL y PHP)?

Tags: php, linux, php5, apache2, lampp

Traté de cambiar en *Ubuntu* en mi `LAMP` el `DocumentRoot` en `httpd.config`, con estos datos:

```
/home/pepe/Escritorio/htdocs
```

Reinicié el servidor web y no se soluciona.

Comment: puede ser debido a permisos `sudo apachectl configtest` que te dice?

Answer (score 0):

En el fichero `httpd.conf` además del parámetro `documentroot` hay que cambiarlo en más lugares.

Por ejemplo:

```
> > <Directory "/LAMP/xampp/cgi-bin">
>     AllowOverride All
>     Options None
>     Require all granted </Directory>
```

Edita el fichero y busca el `documentroot` original, y reemplázalo tantas veces como lo veas.

Busca también si hay algún subdirectorio `includes` dentro del subdirectorio donde está el `httpd.conf`. Ahí hay ficheros de configuración sueltos que pueden marear.